# Unable to make arrays in a list/arraylist

Tags: c#, list, arraylist, unity-container

I need to make array in a arraylist or in a list, I used this:

```
List<string[]> OL = new List<string[]>();
string[] OLdata = new string[7];

OLdata[0] = .. ; OLdata[1] = .. OLdata[6] = ..
OL.Add(OLdata);
```

and I can access it with

```
    OL[0].GetValue(3) or OL[0][3] ..
```

again writing to OLdata and adding it in OL list, when I try to access data with

```
    OL[0][3] ..
```

I am getting the new data which was inserted in array, I am obviously expecting different values in **OL[0][3]** and **OL[1][3]** , whats the reason or any other suggestion ??

Comment: When you write to OLdata the second time how do you do it?

Comment: In your code you have not added a second array. To be honest with you, since I don't see a second `Add` statement I'd say accessing `OL[1][3]` this way should throw an exception. If you've just added OLdata twice, then I would have to +1 @LukeH's answer.

Comment: I think there are mistakes in your question. `OL[0] = ..; OL[1] = ...` should be `OLdata[0] = ...; OLdata[1] = ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays are reference types, so all you're actually doing is altering and then adding *the same array object* multiple times.

You should probably do something like this instead, creating and populating a new array each time:

```
var olData = new string[7];  // create first array
olData[0] = ...  // etc
ol.Add(olData);  // add first array

olData = new string[7];  // create second array
olData[0] = ...  // etc
ol.Add(olData);  // add second array

// ...
```

Comment: o yea..any solution to that ?

Comment: @Rony the "new" on olData needs to be called every time you want a new item in the list.

Comment: +1 - I see in his description where he is simply adding the same object as a second element. He's probably also surprised to see his new addition appearing in OL[0] as well.

Comment: I would argue this really should not be done.  It really sounds like he should make the collection a property of a class and make reference a collection of that class.

Answer (score 1):

When you add your second string array, are you creating a new string[7]?

E.G.

```
List<string[]> OL = new List<string[]>();
string[] OLdata = new string[7];

OL[0] = .. ; OL[1] = .. OL[6] = ..
OL.Add(OLdata);

OLdata = new string[7];

OL[0] = .. ; OL[1] = .. OL[6] = ..
OL.Add(OLdata);
```